# Named query for dates (month and year)

Tags: grails, date, named-query

I have the following domain class:

```
class Car{

 int hp
 Date registrationDate

}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is create a named query that enables me to do something like this:

```
Car.getCarsByYear(2011)
```

and

```
Car.getCarsByYearMonth(2011,11)
```

I'n not sure the second one is possible or if the only way to do it is by having 2 named queries, one for year and one for month.

How do you specify the month/year for a date in a named query? I took some wild shots and tried googling it but I came up with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters to your namedquery :

```
    static namedQueries = {
    getCarsByYearMonth { int year, int month ->
        println "year:"+year
        println  "month:"+month
        def now = Date.parse("yyyy-MM", "${year}-${month}")
        eq 'registrationDate', now
    }
}
```

and call it like this :

```
 def search() {
    render Car.getCarsByYearMonth(2012,2).list()
}
```

Comment: One note: you may want to use the field from marko's question, `registrationDate`, instead of the generic `date`, because it's a little confusing to read.

Comment: I assume he wants the cars whose month/year is equal to the params, not greater than